# Aws managed redis taking around 300ms to send data

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, latency

I am using single Redis node size **cache.m6g.8xlarge** and its taking around 300ms to send data I have both Redis and my application running under same VPC. Same requests in my local is taking 2ms. Is this the usual AWS Redis behaviour

Answer (score 0):

That seems very high.

Try running the redis latency command to ensure that it's just redis

```
redis-cli --latency -h <SERVER> -p <PORT> -a <PASSWORD>
```

Also check your CPU/request rates to ensure you are not hammering the cluster.

Comment: min: 0, max: 7, avg: 0.87 (5374 samples)
This result i got after running the above cmd. Also i checked CPU its less then 2%

Comment: that seems along the lines of what one would expect.  My guess is that some expensive command is getting run.  Check the slowlog https://redis.io/commands/slowlog-get to see if something computationally expensive like KEYS command is being run.

Comment: Okay so the problem is with AWS instance i am using i.e t2.small the lag time is around 250ms there. Any suggestions how i can decrease that b/w i tried with large instances also but not much different

Comment: Are you measuring lag time using the cli latency command above or are you timing around some commands?  If you are timing around the commands in your code, please post what commands are getting run and any results from the slowlog.  If the redis-cli latency is giving you that long - please contact your friendly local AWS support person